# How to delete every second occurence of an element in a nested list - PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list like `[1,[2,1,[2],[3,1,1,[[3]],1,[1]],1],2,1,2,1,3]` and I want to delete every second occurrence of '1' from it for a resultant list of `[1,[2,[2],[3,1,[[3]],1,[]],1],2,2,1,3]`. So far what I've come up with is this:

```
delete_second_occurrence([], [], _, _).
delete_second_occurrence([X|L], [X|R], X, N) :-
   0 is mod(N, 2),
   N1 is N + 1,
   delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N1).
delete_second_occurrence([X|L], R, X, N) :-
   1 is mod(N, 2),
   N1 is N + 1,
   delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N1).
delete_second_occurrence([E|L], [E|R], X, N) :-
   is_list(E),
   delete_second_occurrence(E, R, X, N),
   delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N).
delete_second_occurrence([E|L], [E|R], X, N) :-
   delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N).
```

To clarify,

- R is the resultant list
- L is the input list
- X is the element I want to be removed
- N is the number of times X has been encountered

It removes every second occurrence in the lowermost level but does nothing for the nested lists. How would I go about removing the duplicates in the nested lists as well?

Comment: Use recursion on `E` as well.

Comment: I did in the  `delete_second_occurrence(E, R, X, N)` predicate above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the fourth clause:

```
delete_second_occurrence([E|L], [E|R], X, N) :-
    is_list(E),
    delete_second_occurrence(E, R, X, N),
    delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N).
```

The second condition is true if `R` is the result of deleting every second occurrence of `X` in `E`. The third condition is true if `R` is the result of deleting every second occurrence of `X` in `L`. Furthermore, `N` must have the same value after calling `delete_second_occurrence` on `E` and `L`. Not many lists have these properties. There are two problems to address:

1. Choose a different variable name in the first invocation of `delete_second_occurrence` and update the head of the clause appropriately.
2. Introduce another argument that represents the state of the accumulator after the recursive call.

Instead of counting the number of times that `X` has been encountered, you can use a Boolean variable. There is no need to perform modular arithmetic. After doing this, you will notice that your program generates one correct solution and several incorrect ones. For example, consider the fifth clause:

```
delete_second_occurrence([E|L], [E|R], X, N) :-
   delete_second_occurrence(L, R, X, N).
```

This clause states that `[E|R]` is the result of deleting every second occurrence of `X` in `[E|L]` if `R` is the result of deleting every second occurrence of `X` in `L`. This is not always true. For example, if `N` is `1` and `E` unifies with `X`, you certainly don't want to include `E` in the output list. Similarly, if `E` is a list that contains `X`, you probably shouldn't generate solutions that simply prepend `E` to the result of the recursive call.